# VBA - Countif error '438'

Tags: vba, error-handling

I'm trying to do COUNTIF in VBA and I'm getting for some resom error '438' and i don't know why.

```
Option Explicit

Sub tools()
'

With Worksheets("Plans")
    .Range("a:ar").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=Cv", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Se"
    .rows("6:6").Select
    .Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    .Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    .ShowAllData
    .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(rows.Count, "e").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C11 = "=COUNTIF(c[5],RC[5])"
    .Range("A2:a" & .Cells(rows.Count, "e").End(xlUp).Row) = Range("A2:a" & .Cells(rows.Count, "e").End(xlUp).Row).Value2
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there were two errors, each throwing '38' error:

```
.Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

since `Selection` is not a valid property of Worksheet object

```
.FormulaR1C11
```

just a typo, since it should be

```
FormulaR1C1
```

Other than that there are some good coding habits to follow like:

- avoid use of `Select` and `Selection`

  set and use direct reference to objects (ranges) instead
- avoid repetitions of same long references by using `With` keyword

  this will avoid typing errors
- avoid referring to entire columns or rows

  and limit ranges to actually used cells

  this especially in the use of Worksheet functions like COUNTIF

so here's the code revised for the errors as well for above mentioned good coding habits

```
Option Explicit

Sub tools()

With Worksheets("Plans")
    .Range("a:ar").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=Cv", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Se"

    With .rows("6:6")
        Range(.Cells, .End(xlDown)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End With

    .ShowAllData

    With .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(rows.Count, "e").End(xlUp).Row)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R1C[5]:R" & .rows(.rows.Count).Row & "C[5],RC[5])"
        .Value = .Value2
    End With
End With

End Sub
```